# Integrating amqplib with React to Consume Real-Time Data from Spring Boot and RabbitMQ

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-messaging

In my project, I have a Spring Boot backend acting as a RabbitMQ producer and an exchange and a consumer. I'm developing a React client that needs to receive real-time data updates from the backend.
On the React client side, I have attempted to use the amqplib library to consume data from RabbitMQ. However, I'm facing challenges in properly integrating and establishing the connection.
Is there any way to consume messages directly from the client side ??

Below are snippets of my Spring Boot producer :

```
@PostMapping("/votingAreaInfo")
String sendMessageToExchange(@RequestBody VotingAreaDTO votingAreaDTO) throws JsonProcessingException {

    rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(exchange.getName(),"",votingAreaService.serializeVotingArea(votingAreaDTO));
    return "Successfully published...";
}
```

And this is the Consumer :

```
@RabbitListener(queues = QUEUE_NAME, concurrency = "10")
public void listener( byte[] messageBytes ) {
    try {
        VotingAreaDTO receivedMessage = votingAreaService.deSerializeVotingArea(messageBytes,VotingAreaDTO.class);
        log.info("received message " + receivedMessage);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```